# How to make Cluster of VM's to access all the VM's in all the terminals

Tags: azure

I have 3 Virtual machines on Azure. I have connected to bastian host to each of them. Now I want to create a cluster like for all three VM's so that I can access all the VM's from all the terminals. Any inputs on how can I achieve this.

I tried by allowing traffic from VM2 and VM3 to VM1. Similarly I repeated to all three VM's by allowing traffic.
But when I used
curl -v telnet://hostname:8080 it says connection failed for all the 3 VM's in each terminal.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried by allowing traffic from VM2 I got the same error like below:

```
telnet://hostname:8080 unable to connect to remote host : connection refused
```

[image]

This error usually occurs, if your application is not listening port 8080 before creating a cluster. Ensure that each VM can communicate with each other use `ping` or `telnet` to verify connectivity between VMs. Make sure you can reach each VM from the Bastion host.

In my virtual machine vm1 when I check port are listening on my IP address, it listens to port 80 by default like below.

```
netstat -tulpn
```

[image]

If the application of vm listen port 80 you can use `curl -v telnet://hostname:80` and now I check the communion of vm its connected successfully like below:

[image]

Make use of `netstat` command to check if your application on VM2 is listening on port 8080. The output indicates that, it's listening on `0.0.0.0:80`

[image]

Now the traffic is allowing both the vm successfully like below:

[image]

Make sure that your virtual machines have the proper inbound and outbound rules configured in the Azure Network Security Group and the rules are set up properly to permit communication on the desired ports between your VMs.